# AnguarlJS: watch change in service variable and show/hide elements

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

I have a service defined as

`app.service('Auth', ['$http',function ($http) {
        this.isLoggedIn = false;
        this.user = null;
    }]`

and a controller is using it as

```
app.controller('AuthenticationController', ['$rootScope','$scope', '$http', '$location', 'Auth',function($rootScope,$scope, $http, $location, Auth){
    $scope.login = function(){
        Auth.isLoggedIn = true;
        Auth.user = {
            name: "Shahzad Fateh Ali",
            id: 1
        };

        $location.path('/users');
    }}]);
```

My DOM uses it as

```
<header ng-show="Auth.isLoggedIn">...</header>
```

and

```
 <mainmenu ng-show="Auth.isLoggedIn"></mainmenu>
```

Here mainmenu is a Directive.

Now, I want to observe Auth.isLoggedIn and update the DOM based on its value.

Regards,

Shahzad Fateh Ali

Comment: If Auth service is assigned to the scope, this should happen automatically. Is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `$watch` on a function, it doesn't have to be a string name to a property on the scope. So something like this:

```
$scope.$watch(function() { return Auth.isLoggedIn; }, function(value, oldValue) {
  // Do something when it changes
});
```

But I would encourage you to use events here. So your `Auth` service would have a method which you call to say that the user has logged in. The `Auth` service should get `$rootScope` injected, and then `$rootScope.$broadcast()` an event that says that the user has authenticated. Other parts of your application can then listen to that event with `$scope.$on()` and take action when the user logged in.

Comment: Can you give me some running example about how to use $broadcast and $on in my scenario.

Comment: Actually I dont want to process all DOM elements that at using Auth.isLoggedIn. I want that AngualarJS should update DOM when the value change

Comment: I would encourage you to look at this way of handling authentication: https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth. It intercepts HTTP requests that fails, broadcasts an event which triggers the user to log in, and then resumes the failed request.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having problems with isLoggedIn not getting updated in your service, try making it an object instead of just a boolean.  I have had similar issues with two-way binding a boolean variable in my service and the solution was to make it part of an object.  As an example, you could create an Authentication object in your service with attributes of isLoggedIn and authenticatedUser, then in your service return this object.  When you set isLoggedIn and the user you should see it updated in your service as well.